# adding 2nd set of params to grid action column

Tags: magento-1.9

i working in my admin form grid page. i want to add a 2nd set of params to my grid action column
this is what i tried

```
$this->addColumn('action', array(
    'header' =>  Mage::helper('testmodule')->__('Action'),
    'width' => '50px',
    'type' => 'action',
     'actions'   => array(
            array(
                    'caption'   => Mage::helper('testmodule')->__('Edit'),
                    'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit','test' => 1),
                    'field'     => 'id'
            )
    ),
```

you will notice taht i am trying to add the 2nd set of params to the URL:

```
'test' => 1
```

however, it was not added. any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to add URL with parameter which should be clickable. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the extra parameters in like this:

```
'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit/test/1'),
```

This will be similar to ?test=1. If you wanted to add ?test=1&test2=2 then you could do it like this:

```
'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit/test/1/test2/2'),
```